# ZSH: Auto-show completion options while typing

Tags: zsh

I've been experimenting with `predict-on`, `incremental-complete-word`, and the extension `zsh-autosuggestions`.

I'm looking for a way to display the tab complete options like `predict-on` does, but without trying to complete the command from history (`predict-on` writes the completion into the terminal, which I don't want, `zsh-autosuggestions`'s preview is better).  I can't seem to find this behavior in the description of `predict-on`, but it acts like I hit tab whenever I type something and shows the complete options.

`incremental-complete-word` only does the word, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to do this?  If there was a way to disable `predict-on`'s history search that would be exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do that out-of-the-box in Zsh.

But fortunately, I wrote a plugin called [`zsh-autocomplete`](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) that does exactly that. Have a look at the demo there to see if it's what you're looking for. Feedback, bug reports and feature suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do some researches but couldn't find anything like that for zsh. However, you can always use [Fig](https://fig.io) to add a completion dropdown to the terminal (it works with quite a number of terminals) while typing.

Demo screenshot from Fig website:

[image]